# tricky understanding boolean identity law

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-operations

[This](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/boolean/bool_6.html) page states that A term OR´ed with a “0” or AND´ed with a “1” will always equal that term.

But the table in [this](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/boolean-identities/) link contradicts that at least to the best of my knowledge. To be honest I dont fully understand what that table represents I was hoping someone could clarify.

Comment: There's no contradiction? You're saying the first link says `A or 0 = A` as well as `A and 1 = A`, and that's exactly what the second link says. Both are labeled as "Identity" in their respective charts.

Comment: @joe sewell in the table on the second link for the or, does it not say if the left had side operand is 1 then the right hand side operand is also 1? im unsure how the table is mapping it out

Comment: That's the row labelled "Dominance", which states `A or 1 = 1`. ("or" is represented by `+`). The row for "Identity" states `A or 0 = A`.

Comment: @joe sewell sorry i should have made it clear im not referring to the table at the beginning of the page, if you scroll down to where it describes identity in more detail you will see the table im referring to. thanks

Comment: In that table, "LHS" and "RHS" are the two sides of the `=` sign, not the two operands of `or`. It's proving by exhausting every case that `A or 0 = A` by calculating LHS as `A or 0` and comparing it to the RHS `A`.

Comment: @joe sewell so the first two columns are the operands?

Comment: how could a AND 1 = 1 if the variable a was a zero?

Comment: Yes, the first two columns are operands. I don't see any case in the tables under "Identity" that states `A and 1 = 1` when `A = 0`.

Comment: This is not arithmetical multiplication, don't read 0 x 1

Comment: @Cole-p "*a AND 1 = 1*" where does it say that?

Comment: @vlaz it doesnt say that in the article but i read that a variable and'd with a 1 is always equal to 1. i know that doesnt sound right thats why im on here trying to understand

Comment: @Cole-p which article and where exactly is that said? I can't see that claim in either of the two articles you've linked to. Both clearly say that `A and 1` will be equal to `A`, not `1`. What am I missing?

Comment: @vlaz maybe i read it wrong, i understand the and rule now im just a bit fuzzy on the or part

Comment: @Cole-p please be more specific. You've linked to two websites each of which has multiple rules and expressions. Which OR are you referencing? The identity law? And what are you uncertain about?

Comment: @vlaz sorry, i just got overly confused i have made sense of it now. thanks for your help